# Is it possible to use _MatSelectBase to build own select?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I was using material and now I need to build custom ui-kit of several basic components (input, radio-button, checkbox, select etc.). While looking on how things are organized inside @angular/material, I've noticed that e.g. there's `_MatSelectBase` abstract class that wraps the logic of select, while `MatSelect` component class is relatively short. I'm wondering: is it possibe and is it worthwhile to take `_MatSelectBase` and extend it with my own class, with it's own template and custom styles?

Comment: I would strongly advise against using anything prefixed with `_` from Angular Material, those symbols are internal and can change anytime. In this particular case your select would stop working with Angular Material v17 because they recently [removed the `_MatSelectBase` class](https://github.com/angular/components/pull/27632).

Comment: Thank you @JSONDerulo, please post your comment as an answer, so that I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using symbols from Angular Material prefixed with `_`, those are not part of the public API and can change anytime. You can see which attributes are supported in the [Select docs](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api). Everything from public API follows [Angular's release practices](https://angular.io/guide/releases), which also include a deprecation period of minimum two major releases before a functionality can be removed.

In this particular case your code would stop working with Angular 17, because [they recently removed the `_MatSelectBase` class](https://github.com/angular/components/pull/27632).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible to do that. Give it a try and see what happens. Why not?

But if you need to have a custom UI component kit, you'll be better off to just create it yourself. If its only a few basic components as you mentioned, creating a UI library around an already existing one (like Angular Material), would be overkill. It'll affect performance and it might require a lot of dirty work-arounds to make your custom components behave as expected, which isn't considered best practice. Not to mention that Angular Material's components are quite specific in the way they work.